# Optimizing a diagonal matrix-vector multiplication (?diamv) kernel

Tags: c++, performance, matrix

For an (completely optional) assignment for an introductory course to programming with C++, I am trying to implement a diagonal matrix-vector multiplication (`?diamv`) kernel, i.e. mathematically
$$\mathbf{y} \leftarrow \alpha\mathbf{y} + \beta \mathbf{M}\mathbf{x}$$
for a diagonally clustered matrix \$\mathbf{M}\$, dense vectors \$\mathbf{x}\$ and \$\mathbf{y}\$, and scalars \$\alpha\$ and \$\beta\$. I believe that I can reasonably motivate the following assumptions:

1. The processors executing the compute threads are capable of executing the SSE4.2 instruction set extension (but not necessarily AVX2),
2. The access scheme of the matrix \$\mathbf{M}\$ does not affect the computation and therefore temporal cache locality between kernel calls does not need to be considered,
3. The matrix \$\mathbf{M}\$ does not fit in cache, is very diagonally clustered with a diagonal pattern that is known at compile time, and square,
4. The matrix \$\mathbf{M}\$ does not contain regularly occurring sequences in its diagonals that would allow for compression along an axis,
5. No reordering function exists for the structure of the matrix \$\mathbf{M}\$ that would lead to a cache-oblivious product with a lower cost than an ideal multilevel-memory optimized algorithm,
6. The source data is aligned on an adequate boundary,
7. OpenMP, chosen for its popularity, is available to enable shared-memory parallelism. No distributed memory parallelism is necessary as it is assumed that a domain decomposition algorithm, e.g. DP-FETI, will decompose processing to the node level due to the typical problem size.

Having done a literature review, I have come to the following conclusions on its design and implementation (this is a summary, in increasing granularity, with the extensive literature review being available upon request to save space):

1. "In order to achieve high performance, a parallel implementation of a sparse matrix-vector multiplication must maintain scalability" per White and Sadayappan, 1997.
2. The diagonal matrix storage scheme,
   $$\DeclareMathOperator{\vec}{vec}\DeclareMathOperator{\val}{val}
   \vec\left(\val{(i,j)}\equiv a_{i,i+j}\right)$$
   where \$\vec\$ is the matrix vectorization operator, which obtains a vector by stacking the columns of the operand matrix on top of one another. By storing the matrix in this format, I believe the cache locality to be as optimal as possible to allow for row-wise parallelization. Checkerboard partitioning reduces to row-wise for diagonal matrices. Furthermore, this allows for source vector re-use, which is necessary unless the matrix is re-used while still in cache (Frison 2016).
3. I believe that the aforementioned should *always* hold, before vectorization is even considered? The non-regular padded areas of the matrix, i.e. the top-left and bottom-right, can be handled separately without incurring extra cost in the asymptotic sense (because the matrix is diagonally clustered and very large).
4. Because access to this matrix is linear, software prefetching should not be necessary. I have included it anyways, for code review, at the spot which I considered the most logical.

The following snippet represents my best effort, taking the aforementioned into consideration:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <type_traits>

#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>

#include <omp.h>

#include "tensors.hpp"


#define CEIL_INT_DIV(num, denom)        1 + ((denom - 1) / num)

#if defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)
#define AGNOSTIC_UNROLL(N)              unroll (N)
#elif defined(__CLANG__)
#define AGNOSTIC_UNROLL(N)              clang loop unroll_count(N)
#elif defined(__GNUG__)
#define AGNOSTIC_UNROLL(N)              unroll N
#else
#warning "Compiler not supported"
#endif

/* Computer-specific optimization parameters */
#define PREFETCH                        true
#define OMP_SIZE                        16
#define BLK_I                           8
#define SSE_REG_SIZE                    128
#define SSE_ALIGNMENT                   16
#define SSE_UNROLL_COEF                 3


namespace ranges = std::ranges;


/* Calculate the largest absolute value ..., TODO more elegant? */
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto static inline largest_abs_val(T1 x, T2 y) {
    return std::abs(x) > std::abs(y) ? std::abs(x) : std::abs(y);
}


/* Define intrinsics agnostically; compiler errors thrown automatically */
namespace mm {
    /* _mm_load_px - [...] */
    inline auto load_px(float const *__p) { return _mm_load_ps(__p); };
    inline auto load_px(double const *__dp) { return _mm_load_pd(__dp); };

    /* _mm_store_px - [...] */
    inline auto store_px(float *__p, __m128 __a) { return _mm_store_ps(__p, __a); };
    inline auto store_px(double *__dp, __m128d __a) { return _mm_store_pd(__dp, __a); };

    /* _mm_set1_px - [...] */
    inline auto set_px1(float __w) { return _mm_set1_ps(__w);};
    inline auto set_px1(double __w) { return _mm_set1_pd(__w); };

    /* _mm_mul_px - [...] */
    inline auto mul_px(__m128 __a, __m128 __b) { return _mm_mul_ps(__a, __b);};
    inline auto mul_px(__m128d __a, __m128d __b) { return _mm_mul_pd(__a, __b); };
}


namespace tensors {
    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    int diamv(matrix<T1> const &M, 
              vector<T1> const &x,
              vector<T1> &y,
              vector<T2> const &d,
              T1 alpha, T1 beta) noexcept {
        /* Initializations */
        /* - Compute the size of an SSE vector */
        constexpr size_t sse_size =  SSE_REG_SIZE / (8*sizeof(T1));
        /* - Validation of arguments */
        static_assert((BLK_I >= sse_size && BLK_I % sse_size == 0), "Cache blocking is invalid");
        /* - Reinterpretation of the data as aligned */
        auto M_ = reinterpret_cast<T1 *>(__builtin_assume_aligned(M.data(), SSE_ALIGNMENT));
        auto x_ = reinterpret_cast<T1 *>(__builtin_assume_aligned(x.data(), SSE_ALIGNMENT));
        auto y_ = reinterpret_cast<T1 *>(__builtin_assume_aligned(y.data(), SSE_ALIGNMENT));
        auto d_ = reinterpret_cast<T2 *>(__builtin_assume_aligned(d.data(), SSE_ALIGNMENT));
        /* - Number of diagonals */
        auto n_diags = d.size();
        /* - Number of zeroes for padding TODO more elegant? */
        auto n_padding_zeroes = largest_abs_val(ranges::min(d), ranges::max(d));
        /* - No. of rows lower padding needs to be extended with */
        auto n_padding_ext = (y.size() - 2*n_padding_zeroes) % sse_size;
        /* - Broadcast α and β into vectors outside of the kernel loop */
        auto alpha_ = mm::set_px1(alpha);
        auto beta_ = mm::set_px1(beta);

        /* Compute y := αy + βMx in two steps */
        /* - Pre-compute the bounding areas of the two non-vectorizable and single vect. areas */
        size_t conds_begin[] = {0, M.size() - (n_padding_ext+n_padding_zeroes)*n_diags};
        size_t conds_end[] = {n_padding_zeroes*n_diags, M.size()};
        /* - Non-vectorizable areas (top-left and bottom-right resp.) */
#pragma AGNOSTIC_UNROLL(2)
        for (size_t NONVEC_LOOP=0; NONVEC_LOOP<2; NONVEC_LOOP++) {
            for (size_t index_M=conds_begin[NONVEC_LOOP]; index_M<conds_end[NONVEC_LOOP]; index_M++) {
                auto index_y = index_M / n_diags;
                auto index_x = d[index_M % n_diags] + index_y;
                if (index_x >= 0)
                    y_[index_y] = (alpha * y_[index_y]) + (beta * M_[index_M] * x_[index_x]);
            }
        }
        /* - Vectorized area - (parallel) iteration over the x parallelization blocks */
#pragma omp parallel for shared (M_, x_, y_) schedule(static)
        for (size_t j_blk=conds_end[0]+1; j_blk<conds_begin[1]; j_blk+=BLK_I*n_diags) {
            /* Iteration over the x cache blocks */
            for (size_t j_bare = 0; j_bare < CEIL_INT_DIV(sse_size, BLK_I); j_bare++) {
                size_t j = j_blk + (j_bare*n_diags*sse_size);
                /* Perform y = ... for this block, potentially with unrolling */
                /* *** microkernel goes here *** */
#if PREFETCH
                /* __mm_prefetch() */
#endif
            }
        }

        return 0;
    };
}
```

Some important notes:

1. `tensors.hpp` is a simple header-only library that I've written for the occasion to act as a uniform abstraction layer to tensors of various orders (with the CRTP) having different storage schemes. It also contains aliases to e.g. vectors and dense matrices.
2. For the microkernel, I believe there to be two possibilities

   a. Iterate linearly over the vectorized matrix within each cache block; this would amount to row-wise iteration over the matrix \$\mathbf{M}\$ within each cache block and therefore a dot product. To the best of my knowledge, dot products are inefficient in dense matrix-vector products due to both data dependencies and how the intrinsics decompose into μops.

   b. Iterate over rows in cache blocks in the vectorized matrix, amounting to iteration over diagonals in the matrix \$\mathbf{M}\$ within each cache block. Because of the way the matrix \$\mathbf{M}\$ is stored, i.e. in its vectorized form, this would incur the cost of broadcasting the floating-point numbers (which, to the best of my knowledge is a complex matter) but allow rows within blocks to be performed in parallel.

   I'm afraid that I've missed out some other, better, options. This is the primary reason for opening this question. I'm completely stuck. Furthermore, I believe that the differences in how well the source/destination vectors are re-used are too close to call. Does anyone know how I would approach shedding more insight into this?
3. Even if the cache hit rate is high, I'm afraid of the bottleneck shifting to e.g. inadequate instruction scheduling. Is there a way to check this in a machine-independent way other than having to rely on memory bandwidth?
4. Is there a way to make the "ugly" non-vectorizable code more elegant?

Proofreading the above, I feel like a total amateur; all feedback is (very) much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is a bunch of code to review here, but the most important part is missing. IMO that part should be added (even if done in an inefficient way) to make the question "complete for review". By the way dot-product is a solvable problem, the efficient ways aren't very pretty but so be it

Answer (score 4):

The functions in the `mm` namespace do not seem to provide any value over just calling the mnemonics directly. I would get rid of these to keep the code simple. Also, do you know the language rules around the use of leading underscores in names by heart? If not, I'd suggest avoiding their use altogether, otherwise I'd caution against it anyway because not everyone knows these obscure rules (referring to the arguments starting with double underline).

You've gone through considerable effort to try to make it fast. Have you benchmarked it? Do you know if your code is actually faster than the naive element wise product of two vectors? (Assuming the matrix is indeed diagonal as you say first, not clustered like you later say). Starting and communicating between threads that distribute the workload is overhead that is likely going to not be worth it for small matrices. How small you ask? Depends on your CPU. Benchmark, benchmark, benchmark! In addition to comparing to the naive implementation (again, assuming the matrix is actually diagonal), I would compare to an existing library like [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) or [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net) to see where your code lands in the grand scheme of things.

I understand this is an exercise, but I'll just point out that if it wasn't, you should totally use one of the existing libraries for this.

I'm not sure if the loop unroll pragmas actually help you, the compiler should do unrolling already to a suitable degree. It seems like this pragma at best does nothing or at worst forces an unrolling when you might not want it (e.g. when debugging or if you want the binary size to be smaller). With that in mind it adds additional complexity to the code. I'd benchmark with and without using -O2 and -O3 and seeing the difference.

I see this a lot with beginner C/C++ programmers, they want to do all the fancy things to make it fast, hand unrolling, extracting common subexpressions etc. What they usually don't know it's that the compiler already does all of this and so much more, and it does it better than what they can do or at least not worse in almost all cases. The compilers we have today are not your grandpa's old compiler, they're amazing at generating efficient code to the point that the best thing you can do is to clearly express your algorithm and intent and let the compiler generate the code.

Case in point, which is faster:

```
int factorial(int n){
    if(1==n)
        return n;
    return n * factorial(n-1);
}
```

or

```
int factorial (int n){
    int ans=1;
    while (n>1){
        ans*=n;
        n--;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

?

We'll it's a trick question because the compiler will generate the same machine code for both, so they're identical. My point being, let the compiler do it's job and worry about expressing your intent clearly. And only if the compiler is failing at generating fast code should you go crazy, but always with benchmark in hand.

Did you know the compiler can generate SSE and other vector instructions where it makes sense of you tell it that it's allowed to? See for example
[this website](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html). I'm sure you can find an equivalent in clang and msvc.

All this is to say... Do you really need the complexity that you're adding? I don't know because you haven't shown me any benchmarks. :)

As for prefetching, I've never seen a case where a manual insertion of a prefetch instruction made any noticeable difference, the CPU prefetchers are generally very good.

I'm going to avoid going into details of reviewing the code because I feel like that's predicated on the outcome of the benchmarking results, and I have a suspicion that you'll likely be surprised by the results and might want to reconsider your implementation.

Hope that helps!

(Written on a phone, sorry for typos and autocorrect)

Comment: Thank you very much! 1) The point of the mm namespace is to overload the intrinsics, 
e.g. _mm_load_ps and _mm_load_pd 2) the __arg follow the conventions in the header files 3) apologies, the matrix is diagonally clustered, not strictly diagonal 4) the matrices are relatively large, in the >300k elements 5) I understand what you mean by optim. compilers, will look into, Hager & Wellein state that such cases difficult to optimize automatically/with hints 6) not able to find an open source diamv implementation, only intel mkl 7) I'll benchmark once I finish (auto)vectorization. Thanks again!

Comment: 2) the convention is reserved for internal use by the compiler, you should not follow it because you're not the compiler and you could get name clashes with internal compiler macros and what not which might not even show up as a compiler error. This is what I meant with language rules around the use of leading underscores. 5) there's been big improvements the last years not sure how old your reference is. Which is why you should benchmark :) 6) for starters you can compare against sparse matrices in Eigen. :)

Comment: One thing to consider, sometimes it's better to add zeros in the vectors to pad out the operations than to have extra code to handle the parts that don't align perfectly into aligned vector reads. If that makes sense.